# eclipse not starting because p4eclipse is throwing AccessException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce, p4eclipse, p4java

I was running **Eclipse Junos on Mac** and had **installed p4eclipse plugin**. After system restart I am **trying to restart Eclipse, but it is throwing exceptions** (as seen in logs).

---

```
    com.perforce.p4java.exception.AccessException: Your session has expired, please login again.

    at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.handleErrorStr(Server.java:4453)
    at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.getDepots(Server.java:2673)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Connection$2.run(P4Connection.java:1057)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Resource.runOperation(P4Resource.java:90)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Connection.refresh(P4Connection.java:1060)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Connection.isSandbox(P4Connection.java:1015)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.decorator.PerforceDecorator.updateSandBoxAndStreamDecoration(PerforceDecorator.java:288)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.decorator.PerforceDecorator.decorateProjectWithConnection(PerforceDecorator.java:275)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.decorator.PerforceDecorator.getProjectText(PerforceDecorator.java:848)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.decorator.PerforceDecorator.decorateProject(PerforceDecorator.java:562)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.decorator.PerforceDecorator.decorateText(PerforceDecorator.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.FullDecoratorDefinition.decorateText(FullDecoratorDefinition.java:134)
```

Also, below stack trace:

```
 !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.security 4 0 2013-05-31 11:14:09.882
 !MESSAGE Secure storage was unable to retrieve the master password from the OS keyring. 

 Make sure that this application has access to the OS keyring. 
 If the error persists, the password recovery feature could be used, or secure storage can be deleted and re-created.


 java.lang.SecurityException: Could not obtain password.  Result: -25300
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.osx.OSXProvider.getPassword(Native Method)
    at           org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.osx.OSXProvider.getPassword(OSXProvider.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.PasswordProviderModuleExt.getPassword(PasswordProviderModuleExt.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.getModulePassword(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.getPassword(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.get(SecurePreferences.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesWrapper.get(SecurePreferencesWrapper.java:106)
    at com.perforce.team.core.P4SecureStore.get(P4SecureStore.java:36)
    at com.perforce.team.core.ConnectionParameters.getPassword(ConnectionParameters.java:265)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.P4ConnectionManager.handleLoginError(P4ConnectionManager.java:374)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.P4ConnectionManager.internalRetry(P4ConnectionManager.java:803)
    at com.perforce.team.ui.P4ConnectionManager.shouldRetry(P4ConnectionManager.java:833)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Connection.handleError(P4Connection.java:1649)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Resource.runOperation(P4Resource.java:94)
    at com.perforce.team.core.p4java.P4Connection.refresh(P4Connection.java:1060)
```

---

I have seen this issue before also, and at that time I was left with no other option but to reinstall Eclipse.

Please help me resolve this issue. Also, how to avoid hitting this issue again.

Thanks in advance.

UW.

Comment: Problem most probably is not with eclipse. But with the p4 plugin. Try re-installing the plugin. Also this hints the problem " !MESSAGE Secure storage was unable to retrieve the master password from the OS keyring." -- can you login with p4 standalone client.

Comment: Ya Sajith, I can login with p4 client. Also, for reinstalling p4 plugin, can I do it by changing some conf file in Eclipse, since I cannot actually start Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391455

The bug suggests you go to 'Preferences / General / Security / Secure Storage' and turn of 'OS X Keystore Integration'